# Replacing a child node with another node without affecting its sub node

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need to replace the child node with another node without affecting its sub nodes, I tried matching the child node but was unable to

This is the xml format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
    <Header>
    <MessageId>{A124-B421-C325-D467}</MessageId>
    <Action>find</Action> 
    </Header>
      <Body>
        <MessageParts xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
          <Run xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Run">

            <RunObject class="entity">
              <A1>NA</A1>
              <A2>False</A2>
              <Object class="entity">
               <A3>02</A3>
              </Object>
              <A4>ER</A4>
            </RunObject>
          </Run>
        </MessageParts>
      </Body>
    </Envelope>
```

This is the xml format that i require

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
<Header>
<MessageId>{A124-B421-C325-D467}</MessageId>
<Action>find</Action> 
</Header>
<Body>
<Document>

      <Item>
        <A1>NA</A1>
        <A2>False</A2>
        <Base>
         <A3>02</A3>
        </Base>
        <A4>ER</A4>
      </Item>


</Document>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

This is the code that i through which i tried to change the format

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message"
xmlns:r="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Run"
exclude-result-prefixes="m r">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<!-- move all elements to no namespace -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>


  <!-- rename MessageParts to Document + skip the Run wrapper -->
  <xsl:template match="m:MessageParts">
    <Document>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r:Run/*"/>
    </Document>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- rename RunObject to Item + reorder child nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="r:RunObject[@class='entity']">
    <Item>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r:A1" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r:A2" />
      <xsl:template match="r:Object[@class='entity']>
       <Base>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="r:A3" />
       </Base>
      </xsl:Template>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r:A4" />
    </Item>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried matching the Object element but was unable to since i am already matching its parent element that is RunObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that you cannot define a template inside of a template. So move the `<xsl:template match="r:Object[@class='entity']>` to the root level and add an `<xsl:apply-templates select="r:Object" />` at its place.

The stylesheet could look like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message" xmlns:r="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Run" exclude-result-prefixes="m r">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- move all elements to no namespace -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- rename MessageParts to Document + skip the Run wrapper -->
  <xsl:template match="m:MessageParts">
    <Document>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r:Run/*"/>
    </Document>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- rename RunObject to Item + reorder child nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="r:RunObject[@class='entity']">
    <Item>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r:A1" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r:A2" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r:Object" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="r:A4" />
    </Item>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="r:Object[@class='entity']">
    <Base>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="r:A3" />
    </Base>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is (nearly) as desired:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope>
    <Header>
        <MessageId>{A124-B421-C325-D467}</MessageId>
        <Action>find</Action>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Document>
            <Item>
                <A1>NA</A1>
                <A2>False</A2>
                <Base>
                    <A3>02</A3>
                </Base>
                <A4>ER</A4>
            </Item>
        </Document>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I added the adjective "nearly", because this result has no namespace, while the sample of your desired outcome is in the namespace

```
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message"
```

But because you defined a template that removes the namespaces of *all elements*, I did ignore that. I simply assume that this part of your question is erroneous.

---

If you like to change that, restrict the first template and add a general *identity template*:

```
<!-- move all elements to no namespace -->
<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri() != 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message']">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This would make your output containing the root namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
    <Header>
        <MessageId>{A124-B421-C325-D467}</MessageId>
        <Action>find</Action>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Document xmlns="">
            <Item>
                <A1>NA</A1>
                <A2>False</A2>
                <Base>
                    <A3>02</A3>
                </Base>
                <A4>ER</A4>
            </Item>
        </Document>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```